# Some nitpicks on Lorentz invariance

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I'm trying to understand the exact mathematics of Lorentz invariance and I have a question. I hope this is a good place to ask.

To prove that $J^\mu dt=\rho dx^\mu$ defines a $4$-vector, my book says that for a small charged particle occupying the volumes $dV$ with charge density $\rho$ in a certain referential $R$, the quantity $dq=\rho dV$ is evidently a Lorentz scalar, hence, with obvious notations, in a certain referential $R'$ we have $\rho dV = \rho'dV'$. I'd like to make sure I understand what this means, formally.

Let's forget this particular setting and suppose $\rho$ is just the  density of charge in the entire universe, as in the Maxwell equations for instance.  Now let $M$ be the Minkowski space-time and $G$ the Lorentz group, acting on $M$. Formally one can think of $\rho$ as a function $M \to \mathbb{R}$. Am I right in saying that what is meant is generally that $g \in G$ acts on such functions $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ by $(gf)(x)=f(g^{-1}x)$ , or, in this particular case, that $\rho'$ is gotten from $\rho$ by precomposing with the inverse of the Lorentz transform going from the basis corresponding to $R$ from that corresponding to $R'$?

Now this doesn't really make sense here: $dq$ is a scalar, $dV$ is, too, so $\rho$ can't be a function, so what is meant is surely that there is a constant $C$ and the function $\rho$ as in the preceding paragraph is exactly constant and equal to it in the region $dV$ and null outside of it. Since $dV'$ can have a different shape, $\rho'$ is a function equal to a possibly different constant $C'$ in the region $dV'$ and, likewise, null outside of it. The first equality is then to be understood as $CdV$=$C'dV'$.

This is not really a question about relativity especially, since the same problem happens with just classical space translations (you can't have $f(x)=f(x-x_0)$ if $f$ is nonzero only on a small particle).

Comment: *$J^\mu dt=\rho dx^\mu$ defines a $4$-vector* Does your book really say that?

Comment: Which book? Which page?

Comment: Well, the 4-current has coordinates $J^\mu = \rho dx^\mu /dt$, no? The time $t$, charge density $\rho$ and positions $x^\mu$ all corresponding to a particular referential. Where's the problem? I'm using notes from a class in French.

Comment: I elaborate on this point somewhat in my answer, but note that $dV$ is *not* a Lorentz scalar - it transforms non-trivially under boosts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lorentz transformations don't act on spacetime itself - they act on *coordinates*.
Formally, given an open neighborhood $U\subseteq M$ and a coordinate chart map $x:U \rightarrow V \subseteq \mathbb R^4$, a function $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb R$ induces a function $f_x:V \rightarrow \mathbb R$ via

$$ f_x(a,b,c,d) = (f\circ x^{-1})(a,b,c,d)$$

The distinction is crucial - $f$ is a function on *spacetime*, whereas $f_x$ is the chart image of $f$ in the chart $(U,x)$.  A Lorentz transformation is a change of chart, which means that at the manifold level it does nothing at all.

That is, a Lorentz transformation is a linear coordinate transformation from a chart $(U,x)$ to another chart $(U,y)$, where

$$y^\mu = (y\circ x^{-1})^\mu =\Lambda^\mu_{\ \ \nu} x^\nu$$

Accordingly, the chart representation of $f$ transforms as follows:

$$f_y = f\circ y^{-1} = f\circ (x^{-1} \circ x) \circ y^{-1} = f_x \circ (x\circ y^{-1})$$
and so

$$f_y ( a,b,c,d) = f_x\big( \big(\Lambda^{-1}\big)(a,b,c,d)\big)$$

This is typically expressed as $f'(x) = f(\Lambda^{-1} x)$.

---

Now to more directly address your question.

> Formally one can think of $\rho$ as a function $M\rightarrow \mathbb R$

The charge density $\rho_{(x)}$ is a function which lives in a chart.  It is not clear whether it can be "lifted" to the manifold level, and in fact in this case it cannot.

The reason for this is that $\rho_{(x)}$ is not Lorentz-invariant.  Consider some total charge $Q_{(x)}$ uniformly distributed in a stationary box of volume $V_{(x)}$, where the subscript $(x)$ refers to the chart that we are working in.  The charge density inside the box is $\rho_{(x)} = \frac{Q_{(x)}}{V_{(x)}}$.  If we boost to another frame with coordinates $y$, then $V_{(y)} = V_{(x)} \sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$ where $v$ is the speed of the second reference frame with respect to the first; this is the Lorentz contraction effect.

If we further suppose that $Q_{(y)}=Q_{(x)}$ (i.e. that electric charge does not change under Lorentz transformations$^\dagger$), then it follows that

$$\rho_{(y)} = \frac{\rho_{(x)}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\equiv \gamma \rho_{(x)}$$

Or, to use the notation from before,

$$\rho'(x) = \gamma \rho\big(\Lambda^{-1} x\big)$$

This is different from the transformation law one obtains for the chart representation of a function $M\rightarrow \mathbb R$, so evidently $\rho_{(x)}$ cannot be lifted to well-defined function at the manifold level - that is, it is not a Lorentz scalar.

---

We can go a step further.  Note that if a vector field $\mathbf V$ is defined at the manifold level, it takes the following form in a chart $x$:

$$\mathbf V = V^\mu_{(x)}(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$$

Making the same transition as before, we note that 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\mu} = \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial y^\mu} \frac{\partial}{\partial \nu} = \big(\Lambda^{-1}\big)^\nu_{\ \ \mu} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}$$

and so

$$\mathbf V = V^\mu_{(y)}(y) \frac{\partial}{\partial y^\mu} = V^\mu_{(y)}\big(\Lambda^{-1}\big)^\nu_{\ \ \mu} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}$$
$$\implies V^\mu_{(y)}(y) = \Lambda^\mu_{\ \ \nu} V^\nu_{(x)}\big(\Lambda^{-1} y\big)$$

which means that components of vector fields transform as

$$(V')^\mu(x) = \Lambda^\mu_{\ \ \nu} V^\nu\big(\Lambda^{-1} x\big)$$
under Lorentz transformations.  Comparing this to the above expression for $\rho$, we note that $\rho$ transforms like the time component of the four vector field $J^\mu_{(x)} = (c\rho_{(x)}, 0,0,0)$, which motivates the definition of the 4-current.

---

$^\dagger$ It would not be unreasonable to feel that this step is unjustified, and from a certain standpoint it is.  However, by making this postulate and working under the assumption it is true, then we arrive at results which work beautifully and match all experimental measurements.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you very much. For the first part of your answer, this is what I had in mind but I didn't think of going to charts since I was only dealing with flat Minkowski space.

Comment: @student_du_05 It's important to bear in mind that **any** choice of coordinates (that is, any assignment of numbers to designate a point in spacetime) corresponds to a choice of chart - even if the chart map is as trivial as the identity map on $\mathbb R^4$.  This allows us to distinguish between quantities defined at the manifold level, and quantities which are chart-dependent.  The aforementioned "identity chart" is no more or less special than a shifted version with coordinate origin elsewhere, a rotated or boosted version, or a polar coordinate chart.

Comment: Sorry but why did you erase the second half of your answer?

Comment: @student_du_05 I realized it was not answering the question appropriately, but was too tired to correct it. I will re-edit and tag you in a comment when I’ve done so

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.

Comment: @student_du_05 I've updated my answer.